# that will be / would be the postman

Tags: modal-verbs, modality

If I hear someone ring the doorbell and suspect it is the postman, should I say "That would be the postman" or "That will be the postman"? If both are okay, what is the difference?

Comment: In contexts like this, most native speakers refer to what we think the *current* situation IS by saying what WILL be found to be the case *when we discover the actual truth*. But it's also perfectly idiomatic for at least some speakers to use ***would*** - as if to say, *that's what we **would** find to be the case **if** we looked into it* (which we might not actually do anyway, because the result is a foregone conclusion). Sometimes we ***need*** Past Tense: *"Someone rang the doorbell while I was brushing my teeth", "That **would** be the postman"* (perhaps more often, ***would've been***).

Comment: Are you saying the would-version involves a conditional?

Comment: Could the "would" be an epistemic modal, having nothing to do with conditionals?

Comment: I think that just nets down to how you *describe* the choice of verb tense/mood. As I often say, I don't care much about these labels (native Anglophone rarely know what they mean anyway, so obviously such labels aren't necessary to learn English. From *my* perspective (having just looked up [epistemic modality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistemic_modality) on Wikipedia), I can't really see much difference between *That **would** be the postman* and *That **must / might / may** be the postman*, but neither ***will*** not ***would*** appear at all on that Wikipedia page...

Comment: ...I mean I don't see much difference in terms of them all conveying something about speaker's belief (re something that might or must be true). Obviously there convey different *strengths* of belief. Whatever - I see a "conditional" element on the grounds that we say THAT WOULD BE X to mean ***IF we were to check it out, which we're probably not going to do, THAT'S WHAT WE WOULD FIND*** (ditto with WILL instead of WOULD). But if that perspective doesn't help you understand how the usage comes to exist, just forget I said it.

Comment: According to this paper, citing the work of Ward, G, J. Kaplan, and B. Bimer (2003), the degree of certainty can be expressed by using various kinds of modal
verbs. Consider A: Someone is at the door.
 B: a. That would be Mary.
 b. That must be Mary.
 c. That will be Mary.
 d. That should be Mary.
 e. That may be Mary.
 f. That might be Mary.

Comment: https://semanticsarchive.net/Archive/jI4ZTc0O/Semantics%20of%20epistemic%20modals.pdf

Comment: ". . . It is, however, worth noting that there are differences in the degree of certainty: the certainty goes
down from a-sentence to f-sentence. Epistemic would in B’s response in (2a) conveys the highest degree of certainty of the prejacent proposition that the person who is at the door is Mary."

Comment: YES. that paper you found is very USEFUL to English language learners. It is about degrees of certainty in spoken English.

Comment: I don't claim that knowledge of this kind of terminology is *useless* (or even *counterproductive*) in the context of learning English, but you're certainly ***not*** being well-served by any source that's trying to get you to "learn" that ***That would be Mary*** conveys more certainty than ***That must be Mary***. Frankly, that's just nonsense. Personally, I wouldn't say *either* is more "definite" than the other, but I bet that of those who *do* think there's a difference, the majority would say the ***must*** version is more "unambiguously assertive". But it's a silly distinction.

Comment: Actually, it should be enough of an "acid test" to point out that it's perfectly natural to say *I expect that would be Mary,* but there's something decidedly "odd" about *I expect that must be Mary* (if it *must* be Mary, you *know* that's true, rather than merely *expecting* it to be so).

Answer (score 3):

"Will" implies certainty, while "would" implies a possibility.

"That will be the postman" tells the listener that you're certain the postman is there.  Combined with the future tense, this makes little sense, as there is no guarantee that you can predict the future.

"That would be the postman" tells the listener that you're believing the postman is there.  Combined with the future tense, this makes perfect sense, as there is no guarantee that you can predict the future.

In commonly spoken English, this distinction is often lost; but, if you make the distinction you are seen as a better user of English.

Related to this is the difference between "Can you get the door?" and "Would you get the door?"  The first one asks about physical ability, while the second one asks if someone is willing to perform the action.  There are always people who are physically able to get a door that won't, so better English would have you asking "Would" instead of "Can" when asking for a favor to be performed.

Answer (score 2):

> That'll be the postman.

Is a nice natural thing to say.  In practice you don't need to say anything. It's not uncommon for people to naturally talk to themselves like this, but it's not something that you need to do.  "That'd be the postman" would be fine too. It's not something that you would normally use in an un-contracted form. Using "would" might indicate greater certainty than "will".

I don't want to overanalyse this. But if you do then see [Sematics of epistemic modals](https://semanticsarchive.net/Archive/jI4ZTc0O/Semantics%20of%20epistemic%20modals.pdf)

Comment: I disagree, we often say in English, in hearing a doorbell ring or someone knocking on a door: "Ah, that would be John." And it would be very often non-contracted.

Comment: "We" might, but I wouldn't (!)

Comment: Oh, right, so *you* would say: That'd be John?

Comment: +1 in particular for not wanting to "overanalyse" the usage. Imho, far too many learners are being taught (indifferently observed / recognised) ***tendencies*** in relation to epistemic modals as if they were ***rules***.